# Soap header or http header

Tags: web-services, http, soap, jax-ws

Have a Web application which connects to a jax-ws service. Want to send security credentials in the header. But.. I know that there are two types of headers: 
1) soap header, which I can set with handler in client side 
2) http header in transport layer

Can anybody explain pros and cons of setting additional information in each of these headers? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP headers and HTTP headers are not the same.

The SOAP headers contain routing information, authentication information and so on. It independent of the transport that SOAP uses. If you send the data to the web service then you should place it inside the SOAP headers.
SOAP message passed to the receiver.

HTTP headers contain the content type, the content length, the cache directives for clients, cookies and so on. It independent of the what actually transmitted with HTTP. HTTP headers is intercepted in the web server.

See Also:

- [XML Soap](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp)
- [SOAP Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#soaphead)
- [Message Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)